# Does Malloc allocate the correct space?

Tags: malloc

I have a structure which is passed to a function. There some values should be changed. Back in the main I should read out the new values of my structure.

- In a sample project it works EASILY!
- In my main code in Visual Studio Code with ARM Cortex M3 and a crazy library it DOESNT WORK
  *(**update:** **something must be wrong with compiler:  I checked it hard and observed that not all variables are changed!!!**  )*

My first big goal is to change chip_count within my structure.

**Here the program flow:**

I create a pointer to a special type of structure.
I pass this pointers address to a function.
The function creates a new adress with malloc.
The passed pointer gets this new address.
So it points now on the malloc.
Some variable are of the malloc structure are changed.
Return to main
Access the malloc space and read out the changed stuff
Result:
YES IT WORKS

Sry I added some more functions to understand const declarations better.

---

***Pointer stuff:***
vtss_state_t is the same as struct vtss_state_s
vtss_inst_t in turn is a pointer on struct vtss_state_s or vtss_state_t

the function vtss_create() has a parameter **vtss_inst_t *const inst**
This is a pointer on the pointer of of vtss_sate_s or a pointer to vtss_inst_t.

In the function at the end the adress of malloc is passed to (*inst).
(*inst) is the content of the of the pointer on which inst is pointing to.
So the pointer will point to malloc().

I hope this is right...

---

**FIRST APPROACH ONLINE COMPILER**

I just wanted to see if I can change values in my passed structure.
Result: YES

**FILE:state.h**

```
#include <stdint.h>

/******************************************************************************
                           Structures
*******************************************************************************/

typedef struct tests
{
  int x;
} tests_t;


typedef uint32_t u32;

// This is the structure with  chip_count 
typedef struct vtss_state_s
{
  int a;
  int cookie;
  tests_t u;
  int port_count; 
  u32 chip_count // doesnt change in my real program :(

} vtss_state_t;

// typedef this structure so vtss_inst_t points to it...(?)
typedef struct vtss_state_s *vtss_inst_t;
```

**FILE: main.c**
/******************************************************************************

```
                                Online C Compiler.
                    Code, Compile, Run and Debug C program online.
    Write your code in this editor and press "Run" button to compile and execute it.
    
    *******************************************************************************/
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "state.h"
#define VTSS_PORT_COUNT 1
#define VTSS_PORTS VTSS_PORT_COUNT

// 



// some global structure
vtss_inst_t testspace;
vtss_inst_t *testspace_ptr;

/******************************************************************************
                           functions
*******************************************************************************/

// vtss_inst_get ()
// const adress another access style 
void
vtss_inst_get (const vtss_inst_t inst)
{
  printf ("\ninst get()");
  printf ("\ninst get() adress of inst:%d", inst);
  inst->a = 1111;
}

// This function just should proof that it can change the content 

void
vtss_inst_default_set (vtss_state_t * vtss_state)
{
  vtss_state->port_count = VTSS_PORTS;  // 1
}


//** This is the function which should change "chip_count"
// Man soll einen Pointer auf einen Pointer auf die Struktur C<bergeben (wo sich chip_count befindet )
void
vtss_inst_create (vtss_inst_t * const inst)
{

  printf ("\r\n**vtss_inst_create()");
  vtss_state_t *vtss_state; // temporary pointer  ( just points to a structure )
  vtss_state_t *vtss_state_2;   // just a test compare
  // pass temporary pointer a new memory space:
  vtss_state = malloc (sizeof (*vtss_state));   // is this correct? anyway it also doesnt work without this malloc style
  printf ("\r\n\t malloc=: %d", vtss_state);
  // pass test temporary pointer a new memory space:
  vtss_state_2 = malloc (sizeof (*vtss_state_2));
  printf ("\r\n\t (test) malloc2: %d", vtss_state_2);
  //Test: pass the temporary pointer even deeper & change content of structure where it points to 
  // (change variable port_count to 1)
  vtss_inst_default_set (vtss_state);
  vtss_inst_default_set (vtss_state_2);
  //Test:Change values of the structure:
  vtss_state->a = 1;
  vtss_state->chip_count = 12121;
  vtss_state_2->chip_count = 12121;
  // ** Giving back the new adress from malloc:
  // Test:(from vtss_state or vtss_state2)
  (*inst) = vtss_state;     //passing adress1
  //Test: a should have the correct value:
  printf ("\r\n\ta=1? a =%d ", (*inst)->a);
  (*inst) = vtss_state_2;   //passing adress2
  // Some extra tests:
  (testspace) = vtss_state_2;   // extra Test: pass the adress to a test pointer 
  testspace_ptr = &testspace;   // extra Test: pass the adress to a test pointer 
  (*testspace_ptr) = vtss_state_2;  // extra Test: pass the adress to a test pointer 
  vtss_state_2->a = 22;     // extra Test: change content of test pointer  
  printf ("\r\n\ta=22? a=%d ", (*inst)->a); //

}

/******************************************************************************
                           main
*******************************************************************************/


int
main ()
{
  // **The main structure:
  vtss_state_t state_test;
  state_test.a = 1234;      // pass some test value
  // **pointer to type of vtss_state_t
  vtss_inst_t inst;
  // **pass the adress of the structure!:
  inst = &state_test;

  // Test: add a value to a structure of the structure:
  // (is the same like inst->)
  state_test.u.x = 123;
  // Test: 
  inst->chip_count = 888;

  vtss_inst_get (inst);
  // Test:  I declared two global structure to test global access:
  printf ("\ntestspace points to: %d", testspace);
  printf ("\ntestspace ptr points to: %d", testspace_ptr);
  // Test variable a: 
  printf ("\n1234? inst->a=%d", inst->a);
  // Test: show value of structure in a strucure:
  printf ("\n123? state_test.u.x=%d", state_test.u.x);
  // Test: before & after address is changed:
  printf ("\r\n * Before create(): Adress  inst:%d", inst);
  printf ("\r\n******* Before create():chip_count: %d", inst->chip_count);
  vtss_inst_create (&inst);
  printf ("\r\n\n * After create(): Adress of inst:%d", inst);

  printf ("\r\n\t 22? a:%d", inst->a);
  printf
    ("\r\n even the layer2 function in create() worked:\n port_count=1?: %d",
     inst->port_count);

  printf
    ("\r\n\n\n******* chip_count has changes correctly to 12121: %d\n\n\n",
     inst->chip_count);
  //extra tests with the global structures:
  printf ("\ntestspace points to: %d", testspace);
  printf ("\n  testspace has the correct value a: %d", testspace->a);
  printf ("\n  testspace_ptr has the correct value a:: %d",
      (*testspace_ptr)->a);
  printf ("\n adress of pointer testspace_ptr points to?:%d", testspace_ptr);

// extra test:
  vtss_inst_get (inst);
  printf ("\n there is even access to a:%d", inst->a);


  printf ("\nPE-Hello World");


  return 0;
}
```

---

**SECOND APPROACH: ARM CORTEX M3 in VSC:**

I just want to change **chip_count** but the library function doesn't do it!

```
vtss_rc **vtss_inst_create**(const vtss_inst_create_t *const create, vtss_inst_t *const inst, void (*print)(void))
{
    vtss_state_t *vtss_state;
    vtss_state             = malloc(sizeof(*vtss_state));
    vtss_state->chip_count = 777;
    (*inst)                = vtss_state;
```

I call it in the main: `vtss_inst_create(&create, &inst);`
*( now I also deleted the third test parameter: I should change it here, but result is anyway same)*

**when I read chip_count out in the main :**

```
sprintf(t2, "\r\n main: chipcount should be 777 %d ??", (int)(inst->chip_count));
    print_uart(t2);
```

**Then it prints:**
**482531848** !!!!!!

---

**I copied this function:**

```
void                createtest2(vtss_inst_t *const inst)
{
    vtss_state_t *vtss_state;
    vtss_state             = malloc(sizeof(*vtss_state));
    vtss_state->chip_count = 888;
    (*inst)                = vtss_state;
}
```

it is called: `createtest2(&inst);`

```
sprintf(t2, "\r\n main: wie in create() chipcount 888?: %d", (int)(inst->chip_count));
    print_uart(t2);
```

it prints 888 correctly i guess because it prints it ..

---

**I copied it also with correct header:**

```
vtss_rc     vtss_inst_create3(const vtss_inst_create_t *const create, vtss_inst_t *const inst, void (*print)(void))
{
    vtss_state_t *vtss_state;
    vtss_state             = malloc(sizeof(*vtss_state));
    vtss_state->chip_count = 222;
    (*inst)                = vtss_state;
    (void)create;
    (void)print;

    return 1;
}
```

I call it: `vtss_inst_create3(&create, &inst, spitest);`
*(ignore please the third parameter)*

**it prints out 222 correctly**

How is that possible?
Or is this simply magic :)

**Update:** I checked it and it is shocking to me.
lol
it works in every kind of function but not with that one I want to do it xD

- First I just copied the function but only one parameter. It worked.
- Then I copied it with all parameters. It worked.
- But the original library func. doesn't work.

**In the past I changed the library function a little bit:**

Ok in the past a tuned the library function by adding one little parameter as a little test.
In combination, that it is a library function in not located in the same file it may cause some trouble.
I will now change the header back to normal:
**Normal:**

```
vtss_rc vtss_inst_create(const vtss_inst_create_t *const create,
                         vtss_inst_t              *const inst)
```

**How i tuned it:**

```
vtss_rc vtss_inst_create(const vtss_inst_create_t *const create, vtss_inst_t *const inst, void (*print)(void))
{
```

**update:** lol I rechanged the function it back to normal.
Hmmm....
**Another file?**
Then it must be because the function is in another file or what.

---

I checked inside the functions they point to the same addresses as outside (main).. I mean the value of inst.
**Todo** I print out now the addresses of chip_count
**Update:** OMG something is wrong with the compiler. I compared it as described with similar functions.

---

Same function different result of chip_count.
But another variabale e.g.  "cookie" can be changed!
So one variable is change another not.
This was really confusing to me because I didn't expect it!

---

**CMAKE:**

Maybe there is an error which is suppressed by my CMAKE. So the compiler ignores the error. At runtime the error comes to light.

```
add_target_compile_flags(base PRIVATE "" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-pedantic" "-Wno-format" "-Wno-sign-conversion" "-Wno-switch-default" "-Wno-conversion" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Wno-undef" "-Wno-unused-but-set-variable" "-Wno-unused-function" "-Wno-implicit-function-declaration" "-Wno-uninitialized")
```

---

Comment: sry for the bad question -style. My eyes are burning

Comment: Please provide [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your code as it is right now does not compile, hence impossible to debug. In particular, `(*mainstruct) = ptr;` line is very suspicious: `*mainstruct` is a struct, and `ptr` is a pointer. You cannot assign one to another.

Comment: hi, thank you for your feedback. I wrote it in GDB online Compiler again. It works. But my workspace in Visual Studio the value is not correct at the end. Maybe malloc doesnt work with my cortex m3? I now created a new gloabal variable and pass the adress of it instead of malloc... maybe it works

Comment: Its always like this: I want to add a new variable to my structure. I pass my structure into a function. Something should happen. After the function I read the structure out. NOTHING HAPPENED

Comment: The code compiles now and prints `2121`. Do you expect anything else? I don't see any other values in the code.

Comment: Hi thank you. Correct. I even wrote the code again, based on my library I use. As you can see above. And it still works. It even looks "stable" with all the addresses. But somehow it doesn't work on my cortex m3. I am really sry I don't have any more information since it confused me yesterday a lot and I didn't recorded debug information. But I want to do it today

Comment: it is really crazy. In my arm cortex code it doesnt work with the library function. Right now I deleted the WHOLE commands of the function and put in a simple code. result: chip_count = 48531848 ... BUT I WROTE 777  . then a Test function with the SAME commands CAN change my chip_count to 888, when I read it out in the main.

Comment: lol maybe I should short my first code snippet it is to large---

Comment: There must be a problem with the compiler. Maybe a error is suppressed by my super smart CMAKE flag list. add_target_compile_flags(base PRIVATE "" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-pedantic" "-Wno-format" "-Wno-sign-conversion" "-Wno-switch-default" "-Wno-conversion" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Wno-undef" "-Wno-unused-but-set-variable" "-Wno-unused-function" "-Wno-implicit-function-declaration" "-Wno-uninitialized")

Comment: In the function `vtss_inst_create`, the parameter `inst` is of type `vtss_inst_t *`.  So assigning a `vtss_state_t *` to `*inst` is an error.  Perhaps you want to declare `inst` to be of type `vtss_inst_t **`.  Your compiler should catch that for you.

Comment: hi, thank you. I added some details of my point of view in my answer. vtss_state_t * vtss_state points to a structure. The address of the structure is given by malloc. In the main I need I pass a address of my vtss_inst_t. *vtss_inst_t -> vtss_inst->struct ... so (*inst) is the content of vtss_inst. That means there the struct adress where it is pointing to is just changed ...... Am I right or do I miss something? It would be important if my thinking is bad.

Comment: crazy ... hmm I could decrease the compiler optimatization right? But it is really crazuy. I checked it again. cookie is changed but vtss_count not.. there comes a random number

Comment: wow i still have no idea :)